# CATransaction animation fade in fade out uiviews

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, uiview

I have two views, jumpBarPortrait and jumpBarLandscape I would like to animate between the two so in other words I would like Portrait to fade in while landscape fades out... So far I am able to fade one in but I am not sure how to have the other fade out...

This is my code as it stands currently..

```
[CATransaction begin];
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
animation.type = kCATransitionFade;
animation.duration = animationSpeed;

[self.view insertSubview:jumpBarContainerPortrait belowSubview:actionTabBar];

[[jumpBarContainerPortrait layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"Fade"];
[CATransaction commit];
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't forget [CATransaction flush];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at this method ...

```
        [UIView transitionFromView:jumpBarContainerPortrait
                            toView:jumpBarContainerLandscape
                          duration:0.5
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                        completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
```

Or flip the fromView/toView to transition back.

Answer (score 0):

You insert the view to fade in but not remove the view fade out,try this:

```
[CATransaction begin];
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
animation.type = kCATransitionFade;
animation.duration = animationSpeed;

[self.view insertSubview:jumpBarContainerPortrait belowSubview:actionTabBar];
[[jumpBarContainerPortrait layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"Fade"];

[fadeOutView removeFromSuperview];
[[fadeOutView layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"Fade"];

[CATransaction commit];
```

Comment: hrmmm... this was not animating at all... (meaning no fading at all)